# Is multiple left outer join with coldfusion what I need?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, coldfusion

I have a daily devotional that is emailed to subscribers, built with coldfusion and mySQl.

I currently have 2 churches participating in a trial program. When a participating church makes changes to the daily devotional, the changes are saved in the edited table. 
When the devotional goes out to both churches, a query searches for an edited version first. If present, it sends out the edited version. Otherwise the default devotional will go out to the other church.

I can get the edited version to display by using a left outer join. Unfortunately the edited version is sent out to everyone.

Do I need to use another left outer join or is there another way to fix this problem? 
There are two queries:

**1.    Getclients**

Consisting of 3 Tables  that create the layout, displays the company information, and supplies the subscribers info, all joined by the contact_id.

**SUBSCRIBERS TABLE**

Supplies, email, firstname, timezone, and contact_id

**CONTACT TABLE**

Supplies the information for social links, the footer, company name, unsubscribe information 
contact_id, company,city,state,zip,facebook,twitter,linkedin,youtube,website

**LAYOUT TABLE**

27 fields that supplies  all info for header, footer, and color combinations  for the responsive email joined by the contact_id

My first query to get all email information:

```
<cfquery name="getClients" datasource="#application.dsn#">
select *
from (subscriber INNER JOIN contacts ON subscriber.contact_id = 
contacts.contact_id)INNER JOIN layout ON contacts.contact_id = layout.contact_id
where subscriber.timezone = '4'
</cfquery>
```

**2.    GetDevotional**

Consisting of 2 tables that supply the devotional:

**MOBILE TABLE**

Title, scripture, body, display_date

This is the default table that supplies the daily devotional.

**EDITED TABLE**

eTitle, eScripture, ebody, display_date

Optional table that when info is  present REPLACES the MOBILE TABLE. Otherwise the default devotional will go out.
By using a left outer join in the GETDEVOTIONAL QUERY, I can get the edited version to display, but it is displaying to everybody, not just the church that created the edited version.

```
<cfquery name="getDevotional" datasource="#application.dsn#">
SELECT mobile.mob_id AS id, mobile.display_date AS display_date,
mobile.title AS title, mobile.body AS body, mobile.scripture AS
scripture,edited.edit_id AS edit_id,edited.contact_id AS contact_id,edited.etitle AS 
etitle, edited.escripture AS escripture,edited.ebody AS ebody

FROM mobile
left outer join edited ON mobile.mob_id = edited.mob_id
where mobile.display_date = <cfqueryparam value ="#dateformat(now(), "YYYY-MM-DD")#"
cfsqltype="cf_sql_date">
</cfquery>
```

**The output:**

```
<cfif getdevotional.edit_id NEQ "">
<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;color: #h2_color#;margin-top: 12px;
margin-bottom: 4px;padding-bottom: 0px;">#GetDevotional.etitle#<br />
#getDevotional.escripture#</p>

<p style="text-indent:15px;">
#paragraphFormat(GetDevotional.ebody)#
</p>

<cfelse>

<p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;color: #h2_color#;margin-top: 12px;margin-bottom: 4px;
padding-bottom: 0px;">#GetDevotional.title#<br />
#getDevotional.scripture#</p>

<p style="text-indent:15px;">
#paragraphFormat(GetDevotional.body)#
</p>
```

This problem has brought the entire project to a halt. An suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem that I see is with your database design.  Your edited table does not identify the church that made the edit.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting a query that says, give me x if it's there, otherwise give me y.  A way to do that with almost any database is:

```
select case 
when table3.field1 is not null then table3.field1
else table2.field1
end TheFieldYouWant

from table1 join table2 on something
left join table3 on something
```

Some databases have a function that you can use instead of the case construct.  I could look it up for MySQL, but so could you.

As mentioned in my comment, you still have a database design problem in that you are not storing the church to which the edit applies.  Once you sort that out, you can worry about coding.

Comment: I think the function Dan referred to is Coalesce(). It returns the first non-null value from a list of fields or expressions, or it returns null if all fields are null.